# Baking Souffles

Tags: baking, souffle

I baked individual lemon soufflés
that collapsed before I removed them from the oven. Please advise me
as to what I need to do to keep these items from collapsing. Thanks.

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10177/collapsing-souffle

Comment: Also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/troubleshooting-a-souffle-that-collapses-during-baking?rq=1